# How to access $vars['some'] variables in html.tpl.php template

Tags: theming

In the template.php, I am using the following code for `mytheme_preprocess_page()`.

```
 // Return nid for node of type "interface_configuraitons".
    $nid_config = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('nid'))
        ->fields('n', array('type'))
        ->condition('n.type', 'interface_configuraitons')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchCol();
    //load the configurations
    $configurationNode = node_load($nid_config);
    $interfaceConfig = array();
    $interfaceConfig['driver_url'] = $configurationNode->field_driver_url['und'][0]['value'];
    $interfaceConfig['driver_port'] = $configurationNode->field_driver_port['und'][0]['value'];
    $vars['interfaceConfig'] = $interfaceConfig;
```

While `$interfaceConfig` is initialized and available in any of the page templates, it is `NULL` in the html.tpl.php template. I was trying to run `mytheme_preprocess_html()` without success.

How do I get this preprocessing take place, so it is available in the html.tpl.php template file?

Comment: The `preprocess_html` hook is the right place. Make sure you clear your cache so the new function is registered. You also have a typo in your `db_select()` condition

Comment: the preprocess_html didn't work, but what worked was mytheme_preprocess_html... i was just not clearing the cache as pointed by Clive. Thank You Clive. ps. db_select() seems to work fine

Comment: Then you have a typo in the name of your content type ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule for any THEMEHOOK.tpl.php file (where THEMEHOOK is something like 'html', 'page', 'node' etc.) is:

1. The default variables are set in `template_preprocess_THEMEHOOK()` (eg.
   [template_preprocess_html](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7))
2. Any module can add variables using `MODULENAME_preprocess_THEMEHOOK()` (eg. [toolbar_preprocess_html](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21toolbar%21toolbar.module/function/toolbar_preprocess_html/7))
3. The active theme can add variables using `THEMENAME_preprocess_THEMEHOOK()` (eg. [bartik_preprocess_html](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes%21bartik%21template.php/function/bartik_preprocess_html/7))

The `$variables` array (sometimes called `$vars`) is passed on from function to function in the above order, so each function can expand on or overwrite the variables added before.

Answer (score 0):

A variable that is set from `template_preprocess_page()` or an implementation of `hook_preprocess_page()` made from a module or a theme is not available to the implementation of `hook_preprocess_html()` made from a module or a theme.

A variable is available only to specific preprocess functions, which in your case are:

- `template_preprocess()`
- `template_preprocess_html()`
- `MODULE_preprocess()`
- `MODULE_preprocess_html()`
- `ENGINE_preprocess()`
- `ENGINE_preprocess_html()`
- `THEME_preprocess()`
- `THEME_preprocess_html()`
- `template_process()`
- `template_process_html()`
- `MODULE_process()`
- `MODULE_process_html()`
- `ENGINE_process()`
- `ENGINE_process_html()`
- `THEME_process()`
- `THEME_process_html()`

MODULE is the name of any enabled module, THEME is the theme currently used to render the page, and ENGINE is the name theme engine used from the theme currently used to render the page.

Notice also that all those `*_preprocess()` and `*_process()` functions don't share the variables when called for different template files.

#### Reference

- The documentation for [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)